# User can still run programs that are disallowed by group policy (on one computer)

Tags: group-policy

On one computer, a user can run programs that have been disallowed by group policy. I have check rsop and it shows that setting as enabled and those programs are to be blocked. The user has the same permissions on both computers but can run the program on one and not the other.

If RSOP and gpresult shows that these settings disable functionality, how could it be possible that they are being bypassed?

[image]

*I asked this at serverfault but got no response so deleted it there and reposting here.

Comment: Does it work as expected for other users on that questionable computer? "If RSOP and gpresult shows that these settings are turned off" I'm not sure what you mean by this?  What do you mean "turned off"? Are policies applying to that computer/user or not?

Comment: Sorry, by "turned off" I mean that RSOP is showing that the policy is enabled which disables certain programs and start menu functionality, etc. By all accounts, the gpo is applied but the programs that are supposed to be prevented from running are still running.

Comment: Does the affected user logs in with a fully functional profile, and is this user member of an administrators group which gives him permissions to overcome the domain policy?

Comment: The user is a member of local admins on both computers. However, I have removed from administrators on the troubled computer but still can bypass the policies.

It doesn't appear to be fully functional because the policy does block the command prompt from running still. So I'm not sure why some parts of the policy are running while others are not.

Comment: What is the OS of the computer on which the policy works and the one one which it doesn't? Also, bump on Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's question regarding whether only _certain_ or _all_ users are affected on the non-working computer?